# MediaPlayer debug messges?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm making use of the following code to play *.mp3 file in my app,

```
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(cts, "raw", getPackageName());
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resID);
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

The code works fine.. however there are lots of debug messages that are getting printed repeatedly in the Logcat. I'm planning to publish the app very soon.. I'm just wondering if the above code is right or wrong.

Any pointers?

UPDATE:
here are the messages that are getting printed,

```
05-21 16:32:41.235: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(6000): release
05-21 16:32:41.235: V/MediaPlayer(6000): setListener
05-21 16:32:41.235: V/MediaPlayer(6000): disconnect
05-21 16:32:41.250: V/MediaPlayer(6000): destructor
05-21 16:32:41.250: V/MediaPlayer(6000): disconnect
05-21 16:32:41.250: W/CursorWrapperInner(6000): Cursor finalized without prior close()
05-21 16:32:41.790: V/MediaPlayer(6000): message received msg=2, ext1=0, ext2=0
05-21 16:32:41.790: V/MediaPlayer(6000): playback complete
05-21 16:32:41.790: V/MediaPlayer(6000): callback application
05-21 16:32:41.790: V/MediaPlayer(6000): back from callback
```

Comment: What kind of messages?

Comment: What are the messages. Please post.

Comment: everything below W can easily be ignored... you should see the garbage a samsung device logs... unbelievable...

Comment: @WarrenFaith do you mean these debug messages are not harmful?

Comment: Who should they harm? They are labelled `V` which stands for `verbose`. Not even close to a `warning` or `error`.

Comment: I thought there will be some performance issues because of these repeated messages.. Anyways thanks for your explanation!!

Comment: @Naveen, they are not harmful, they just report what is happening behind the scenes (where you can't see manually)